# In Android, how do I create a popup and submit data to the main view?

Tags: java, android, navigation, popup

I've created a Main.xml with buttons. They all perform a certain action and this is all fine, but there should also be password protected buttons. So I also created a second xml (popup.xml). This should pop up if the user presses the button. In popup.xml there is just a textfield for user input and a button to submit.

At the moment I can press on the button and the popup appears, but I don't know how to submit the user input data to the main view or just go back to the main view by pressing the button.

```
public class BastiLauncherActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button b1;    
    // ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // this b1 is a button in the main view where this pop up should appear
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1Button);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        LayoutInflater inflater =
                (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null,
                false), 200, 300, true);
        pw.setOutsideTouchable(true);

        if (v == b1) {
            // opening the popup
            pw.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.dateiButton), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

        } else if (...) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i think you should have to use Dialog to show some form to fill and then you can get that values from EditText ,refer this link for Dialog with Custom View from any of you xml file.http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see you're using a PopupWindow - to remove it you invoke `dismiss()`.

If you just want a pop up to capture some user input then return back to the Activity that spawned the pop up then I would suggest using a Custom Dialog. You can create whatever you like in the dialog, and add whatever buttons you need with handlers for each button. An example;

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this)
               .setTitle("Enter password")
               .setMessage("Password required for this function")
               .setView(/* You view layout */)
               .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                       Editable value = input.getText(); 
                   }
               }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                       // Do nothing.
                   }
               }).show();
```

Comment: Hi, it's me again. I guess I don't really get it. I put this code in my app and I get an alertbox with a "Ok" and "Cancel" button. They both do nothing. How can I add a Textfield for the User input and check that.

Comment: AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertbox.setTitle("Enter password");
    alertbox.setMessage("Password required for this funktion");
    alertbox.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
//  Editable value = input.getText(); 
}}).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new     DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
}
}).show();